# VoiceOver and NVDA on Chrome ignores aria-label

Tags: html, wai-aria

As you can see, VoiceOver and NVDA read out `Click Me > (greater than)` despite the aria-label set to `Click Me`.

Any ideas why? Is this a current bug?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="submit" aria-label="Click Me" value="Click Me >">
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JAWS on Internet Explorer and NVDA on Firefox are generally the accepted browser + screen reader combinations on a PC.  If a screen reader does not work with Chrome, it's up to the developer/company to decide if it's worth pursuing a workaround.  For Apple products, I've always tested with VoiceOver on iOS devices and not as much with VoiceOver on a Mac.  Either way, Chrome has not worked as well as Safari or Firefox.

One could possibly argue that Chrome is working properly and is adhering to [WCAG 4.1.2 Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-rsv.html) and is surfacing the "name" and "value" of the object.  Both JAWS and NVDA on Chrome say "Click me, button, Click me greater", which is the name, role, and value of the object.

However, Chrome does **not** say "Click me greater" if you use

```
<button aria-label="Click Me">Click Me ></button>
```

so perhaps that's your workaround.

Comment: This won't work because it is a form and I'd like validation. I ended up just wrapping the `>` in a `span` and giving it an `aria-hidden=true` value

Comment: Not sure I understand what part wouldn't work.  The `<button>` workaround?  You can still put it in a form and still have validation.  Hiding the '>' with `aria-hidden` helps but you'll still hear "click me" twice whereas the `<button>` will only say it once.